# Mysql dump with timestamp

Tags: bash, powershell, cmd, mysql

I have a project that uses MySQL database. I want to backup the database every day, so I use this:

```
mysqldump -h host -u user -p password database > 'location.sql'
```

I want the files to be named with timestamp, i.e.:

Today the file will be named `something-07-05-2014 08-00-00`
Tomorrow will be, `something-08-05-2014 08-00-00`

How to append a formatted timestamp with the exported file name ?

Comment: That's not a mysql question that's a question for whatever batch script language you use (windows, bash, perl, python, ...)

Comment: I execute this script from Windows command line or Linux Terminal, both give the same result. My question is how to include timestamp when dumping MySQL database via mysqldump tool

Comment: The filename you specify is not under the control of the tool `mysqldump`. Your question has nothing to do with MySQL and everything with the environment _where_ and _how_ you run this.

Comment: @Ayman: for windows it's more complicated, see i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us. I would recommend you the use of powershell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do

```
mysqldump -h host -u user -p password database > something-$(date +%d-%m-%Y %H %M %S).sql
```

Comment: What shell are you running this in? It doesn't seem to work in `cmd` or PowerShell.

Comment: Doesn't work in Bash either. The command `date +%d-%m-%Y %H %M %S` needs quotes as in @Pranav's answer below.

Comment: Also, once the date formatting is sorted, `mysqldump` returns a syntax error, `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `.sql'` Escaping doesn't seem to help. The `echo` command returns expected results. `echo something-$(date "+%d-%m-%Y %H %M %S").sql` > "something-28-10-2014 10 11 29.sql"

Answer (score 21):

You can use something like this

```
mysqldump -h host -u user -p password database >  $(date "+%b_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S").sql
```